# Не связывать внешний порт машины с внутренним портом контейнера

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Суть вопроса**: Можно ли не выделять внешний порт машины для внутреннего порта контейнера?
То есть, чтобы доступ к порту контейнера можно было получить только через сеть докера, но при этом порт машины под это не занимался.

Имеется подобный `docker-compose` файл:

```yml
version: "3.8"
services:
  registry:
    image: registry:2
    container_name: registry
  
    ports:
      - :5000
    
    ...
```

Как я понимаю, подобная конструкция свяжет рандомный свободный внешний порт со внутренним `5000`, из-за чего придётся закрывать внешний порт, если я не хочу, чтобы до приложения достучались извне.

Пробовал так же указать `ports: []` и не указывать его вовсе, в таком случае, как я понимаю, порт всё равно присваивается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не до конца протестировал, если не указывать `ports` - внешние порты не связываются с внутренними.